# Forward Engineering EER Diagram Produces Error 1882

Tags: foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

I have looked at other forums, including the posts about this error but cannot seem to find the cause of it in my situation. The data types, collation, zero fill, not null, unsigned, and binary types all match and I still cant come up with a solution. The output I receive is as follows:

error: `ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_projects_has_equipment_equipment1' in the referenced table 'equipment'`

Ive included the equipment table as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

code:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Group_13_Schema`.`project_equipment` (
      `project_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `vendor_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `department_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `equipment_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `equipment_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`, `equipment_id`, `project_id`, `vendor_id`),
      INDEX `fk_projects_has_equipment_equipment1_idx` (`vendor_id` ASC, `department_id` ASC, `equipment_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_projects_has_equipment_projects1_idx` (`project_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_has_equipment_projects1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
        REFERENCES `Group_13_Schema`.`projects` (`project_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_has_equipment_equipment1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id` , `department_id` , `equipment_id`)
        REFERENCES `Group_13_Schema`.`equipment` (`vendor_id` , `department_id` , `equipment_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Group_13_Schema`.`equipment` (
  `equipment_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `vendor_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `equipment_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `equipment_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`equipment_id`, `vendor_id`, `department_id`),
  INDEX `fk_departments_has_vendors_vendors1_idx` (`vendor_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_departments_has_vendors_departments1_idx` (`department_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_departments_has_vendors_departments1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`)
    REFERENCES `Group_13_Schema`.`departments` (`department_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_departments_has_vendors_vendors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`)
    REFERENCES `Group_13_Schema`.`vendors` (`vendor_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_has_equipment_equipment1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`equipment_id`)
    REFERENCES `Group_13_Schema`.`equipment` (`vendor_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: How is the error not clear? You reference equipment keys/indexes (`vendor_id` , `department_id` , `equipment_id`) & (`vendor_id`), but you haven't declared both those keys/indexes. Also this is addressed in duplicate FK error answers & in the manual re FK declaration. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index for the 3 FK columns. I would expect that the PK qualifies already, but there the last 2 columns are in the opposite order than what is listed in the FK constraint.